# Eclipse error occurred during Repository registry initialization

Tags: eclipse, maven

I suddenly encountered an error initializing Eclipse Kepler:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Repository registry initialization".
For input string: "(pilgrim's conflicted copy 2013-10-18).gen"
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I found it!!!

Delete the directories inside:

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.core/nexus/
```

And rebuild the maven project.

Note: this also applies to Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Just for others. After deleting them, go to Window> Preferences>Maven>User Settings.. Then click update settings

Comment: My Error was: 
An internal error occurred during: "Repository registry initialization".
For input string: "conflict-20150613-165020.gen"
But deleting the nexus directory solved my problem.

Comment: I don't have nexus folder on my system. Can no longer search the task list...!

Comment: @user2568374 the `.metadata` folder is inside your Eclipse project. (Worked for me, thank you @chiastic-security for the answer!)

Comment: Deleting the nexus directory worked for me. Great solution!

Comment: Works also in Neon

Comment: Thanks John Fadria, this solution resolved the same issue with Oxigen version as well.

Comment: This is still helping.  September 2022 using Eclipse 
Version: 2022-09 (4.25.0), Build id: 20220908-1902 .  Error was:  Repository registry initialization has encountered a problem.
An internal error occurred during: "Repository registry initialization".
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException